# iOS UIWebview not pulling images from cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, uiwebview

XCode 5.1.1 with the iOS 7 SDK building on an iPhone 4s with the latest iOS 7 installed. An app whose sole content is a UIWebView loaded from a Node.js express webserver.

I am using this standard snippet to cache images (javascript):

```
for (var i = 0; i < imagesToPreload.length; ++i) {
    var preload = new Image ();
    preload.src = imageURLsToPreload[i];
    preloadedImages.push(preload);
}
```

Where preloadedImages is a global array. And I'm setting a background image programmatically, a while after those images have loaded, with one of the images in that array (for a fade effect):

```
$(".behindBackgroundImageGraphics").css("background-image",background.css("background-image"));
```

I can guarantee that the URLs of the images preloaded in snippet 1 are the *exact same* as the URLs of the images in snippet 2. I even verify that the image objects are persistent with the following snippet:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < preloadedImages.length; ++i) {
        alert("preloaded image size: "+preloadedImages[i].height+"x"+preloadedImages[i].width+"px");
    }
}, 1000*60);
```

So, the image objects are loaded and kept in memory, and should be paired with the URL from which they were loaded. My UIWebview is configured to pull from cache first in all cases, it's given an 8MB in-memory cache (way more than enough), and a max-age=3600 is added to the cache-control header of the response of all image load requests for this app (verified).

**Problem:** *every time* the "behindBackgroundImageGraphics" div's background image is set (many times over a span of a minute), it fires off a fresh request to the server for that image resource. After that happens, the alert pops up and verifies for me that I still have an image stored for that same url.

I have tried many other common solutions, including loading all the background images into an invisible element (even a visible one in my desperation - where I could see the images had loaded). Does anybody know the problem, solution, and/or workaround? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry for the long post.